# How can i do exponent function in c?

Tags: c

I Would like to know how I can do exponent function in this code part (that means how I can change ^ to something that works in c language)?

```
    K = (S * (P/100/12)) / (1 - (1 + (P/100/12))^(-Y*12) );
```

Comment: .... and realise that `^` is a bitwise operator in C that only accepts integral operands.  It is not an exponentiation function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [`pow()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pow.3.html) function from *math.h*

```
K = (S * (P / 100 / 12)) / (1 - pow((1 + (P / 100 / 12)), (-Y * 12)));
```

Comment: Is `pow` in the right place? Surely `(...) / (1 - pow(...))`

Comment: @iharob Are you sure that pow is in the right place? I'm asking it because it won't give me the answer that i'm supposed to get :)

Comment: Sorry, I think it wasn't. Now?

Comment: @iharob Now it gives me the answer that i want. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <math.h>
```

and use the [`pow`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_pow.htm) function

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is pow() and that's found in the math.h library. Just remember to compile with -lm or it will not let you compile it.

Example : gcc -o output_name file.c -lm

Comment: I didn't have any problems with compiling. Thanks for the info anyway :)